# how to test setter and getter?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

how to test setters and getters?

```
function someClass(){
   var data;

   this.setData = function(value){
       // some complex logic
   }

   this.getData = function(){
      // some complex logic
   }
}
```

is it right way for execute setData and getData for test it bouts in one test case?

Comment: I'd test those functions.  This looks like JavaScript.  What are you using for testing framework?

Comment: Usually getters and setters are expected to not perform any kind of logic...

If "some complex logic" is doing one thing (SRP - single responsibility principle) then you can write a simple test that checks it.

If these functions are doing different things you should have different tests for each.

Comment: @alfasin, how do you test each method separately if they use private variable?

Comment: @duffymo, is it possible to check those function separately using any framework?

Comment: Why not?  You wrote them, didn't you?

Comment: you shouldn't care how the function is doing its thing (private variable and what not) - you're testing the function not the variable.

Comment: @alfasin, as I see it, the problem is that you can't test setter and getter separately from each other, if you use private variables

Comment: @duffymo, can you show how? The accepted answer uses both setter and getter in one test

Comment: I think the accepted pseudo code is fine.  I'd get on with it.

Comment: @duffymo, ok, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
function yourTest() {
  var sc = someClass()

  sc.setData(someInputValue1)
  assert.equals(someExpectedValue1, sc.getData())

  sc.setData(someInputValue2)
  assert.equals(someExpectedValue2, sc.getData())
}
```